# Export excel from table tools not showing in IE but working with chrome

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatable. I need export excel and clolVis(col visible / hide) button in toolbar. I used following code but export excel button is not displaying in IE. I'm using IE10.

```
function DrawAllFundTable() {
    $("#AllFundsData").empty();
    $("#AllFundsData").html('<table class="display table table-hover table-striped VF-table"  width="100%" id="AllFundsData-Table"></table>');

    AllFundsTable = $('#AllFundsData-Table').dataTable({
        "data": AllFundDataEquity,
        "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
        "dom": 'T<"clear">ft<"bottom"p>',

        "language": {
            "sSearch": "Search"
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "columnDefs": [
        { "targets": [0], "searchable": true, "visible": true, "title": "Fund", "sortable": true, "className": "col-xs-3" },
        { "targets": [1], "searchable": true, "visible": false, "title": "Sub Type", "sortable": true, "className": "col-xs-1" },
        .....Other columns....
        ],     
       "sDom": '<"toolbar">lC<"H"Tfr>t<"F"p>',

                "oColVis": {
                    "buttonText": "Show / hide columns",
                    "bRestore": true,
                    "sAlign": "left"
                },
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sAlign": "left",
                    "sSwfPath": "assets/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",

                    "aButtons": [ 
                        {
                          "sButtonText": "Export to Excel",
                            'sExtends':'xls',
                            'mColumns':'visible', //set which columns here
                            "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                            "sButtonClass": "back_image"
                        }  ]
                }

  });      


}
```

This working fine with Chrome but I need it should work in IE.

*Datatable JS*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.2/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.1.3/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
    --%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
```

*CSS*

```
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.2/css/dataTables.colVis.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <%-- <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.1.3/css/dataTables.colReorder.css" rel="stylesheet" /> --%>
    <link href="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: You have Flash disabled in chrome, thats why it doesnt work.